# Why am I getting a timeout when executing a query against an Aurora Serverless instance from a Go lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-rds, serverless-framework, aws-sdk-go, aws-aurora-serverless

This is my first attempt at using a lambda with Aurora Serverless(postgres).  I wrote some code to essentially be able to check that the connection is working, but it's not clear to me why I am getting a timeout when I try to execute the query.

This code seems pretty straightforward.  Is there something I'm missing about the serverless environment?

```
func connect() (*sql.DB, error) {
    dbName := "my_db"
    dbUser := "app_user"
    dbHost := "REDACTED.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com"
    dbPort := 5432
    dbEndPoint := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", dbHost,dbPort)
    region := "us-east-2"


    creds := credentials.NewEnvCredentials()
    authToken, err := rdsutils.BuildAuthToken(dbEndPoint, region, dbUser, creds)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("ERROR: %v \n", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s \n",
        dbHost, dbPort, dbUser, authToken, dbName,
    )

    return sql.Open("postgres", dsn)
}


func Healthcheck() (bool, error) {
    db, err := connect()
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    defer db.Close()

    var result int
    err = db.QueryRow("Select 1").Scan(&result)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    fmt.Printf("Result: %v\n", result)

    return true, nil
}
```

Comment: Can you share the error message you're receiving? Are you seeing the whole lambda execution timeout, or receiving an error that indicates the connection timed out, or receiving an error that the query itself timed out? It may be hard to tell between the latter two as-is; consider using error wrapping and returning `fmt.Errorf("connect() timed out: %w")` for the connection error and `fmt.Errorf("select timed out: %w")` for the query error.

Comment: Can you connect to your database through other means such as your SQL client? You might want to check the networking configuration first if you think your code should work as it is.

Comment: The query is what times out. I added debugging code and the connection is created with no errors reported. It's QueryRow().Scan() never responds.  Is it worthwhile to separate them and see which one is having the issue or is that irrelevant?

Comment: I have the same error on insert, conection is ok, ping is ok (ping query : select 1) but when I open a transaction and use exec on it with a line, my lambda timeout (15s, 30s all the same) without error from connection, and never get past the exec statement